# wix - Install pre-requisite MSI based on feature

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I'm using Wix v3.5. I need to install an MSI as part of a particular feature. Is this possible? Or do I have to upgrade to 3.6 and "BURN" it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burn was first introduced in WiX v3.6. It can manage installing multiple packages as part of a chain packages.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to run one .msi from inside another .msi. That requires a bootstrapper/chainer like Burn.